# How to find New Page is started or not, working with itextsharp in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, itext

I have a data-set in which multiple records are available and I am creating PDF from it.
Data of each record is not fix it may contain any number of pages, now I want to add the last name at the end of each page. whenever I want do it with the footer same name has been display on each page but I want the name of person whose record is printing.

here is my code
@ K.C.

```
    Document document = new Document();
    //PdfWriter writer =  PdfWriter(document, Response.OutputStream);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);

    document.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["ab"].Rows.Count ; i++)
    {

       // calling PDFFooter class to Include in document
        footer = ds.Tables["ab"].Rows[i]["lName"].ToString();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.SetWidths(new int[] { 3, 3 });
        table.SpacingBefore = 5f;


        PdfPCell cell;
        Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
        var blackListTextFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10f, Color.WHITE);
        var innerrtextFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 7f, Color.BLACK);
        phrase.Add(new Chunk(ds.Tables["ab"].Rows[i]["header"].ToString(), blackListTextFont));
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(phrase));
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.Padding = 5f;
        cell.BackgroundColor = new Color(85, 142, 213); 
        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.CompleteRow();
        writer.PageEvent = new PDFFooter(ds.Tables["ab"].Rows[i]["lName"].ToString());
        document.Add(table);
        document.NewPage();

    }
    document.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= SampleExport.pdf");
    Response.End();
    Connection.Close();
}

public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
    PdfPTable tabFot = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1F });
    PdfPCell cell;
    tabFot.TotalWidth = 300F;
    string lname = cp;
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(lname));
    tabFot.AddCell(cell);
    tabFot.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 150, document.Bottom, writer.DirectContent);
    lname = null;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code you tried?

Comment: You are using page events, aren't you?

Comment: Maybe you are using `PdfPTable`? Your question isn't clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: @MKL yes i am using endOfPage event for this, but every time the footer has been combine with the previous one and then print.

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
writer.PageEvent = new PDFFooter(ds.Tables["ab"].Rows[i]["lName"].ToString());
```

in a loop to update the `PageEvent` of the `PdfWriter`.

Unfortunately this C# syntax (just like the use of a setter in case of iText/Java) is misleading:

```
    public virtual IPdfPageEvent PageEvent {
        get {
            return pageEvent;
        }
        set {
            if (value == null) this.pageEvent = null;
            else if (this.pageEvent == null) this.pageEvent = value;
            else if (this.pageEvent is PdfPageEventForwarder) ((PdfPageEventForwarder)this.pageEvent).AddPageEvent(value);
            else {
                PdfPageEventForwarder forward = new PdfPageEventForwarder();
                forward.AddPageEvent(this.pageEvent);
                forward.AddPageEvent(value);
                this.pageEvent = forward;
            }
        }
    }
```

> *([PdfWriter.cs](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfWriter.cs))*

Thus, your code line quoted above does **not *replace*** the current `PageEvent` instance but instead ***add*** to it which explains your observation from your comment:

> every time the footer has been combine with the previous one and then print

You either have to first clear the existing page event:

```
writer.PageEvent = null;
writer.PageEvent = new PDFFooter(ds.Tables["ab"].Rows[i]["lName"].ToString());
```

(cf. the special treatment of a `null` value above) or use a single `PageEvent` implementation  instance in which you only change a member variable which in turn is used as footer text.